# Running .Net 4.0 Winform app from share (UNC path)

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

Has anyone been successful running a .Net 4.0 winforms application from a UNC share? I tried to make it compatible with 2.0 security and using the Level 1 transparency model but from what I can see it is nearly impossible. I also tried all caspol combinations I could think of, from Framework and Framework64, 2.0 and 4.0 to no avail.

Also - if this is the wrong thing to do, that is, "never run an app from a share", what is the alternative to have hundreds of clients *installing* and  *updating* their winform app without requiring someone to sit on every single machine and reinstalling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was under the impression that running from a share is allowable in .NET 4.0, whereas it wasn't in 2.0 (not sure about 3.0 and 3.5, but I'd think since they both sat atop CLR 2.0, it would mimic the 2.0 behavior).  My guess is that your 2.0 security compatibility is the issue.

However, I would say that an alternative is ClickOnce deployment.  You can publish it to a share, and have it check for updates at program start.  Also, you can force upgrades with a required minimum version entry.

Comment: Would Click Once enable running in FullTrust? The reason I need that is due to frameworks such as Spring.Net that require full trust and do a lot of reflection work. Thanks!

Comment: Within the security tab of your project, there is an option for "Enable ClickOnce security settings".  Also found there, is the choice between "This is a full trust application" and "This is a partial trust application."  I don't have experience in partial trust via ClickOnce, but seemingly one has the ability to specify some options.  There is an "Edit Permissions XML" button that looks promising.

Comment: Thank you, Mike - I'll go down this route.

Comment: Running from a network share is perfectly okay.  I have deployed 5 different WPF 4.0 apps to a network share, and all users are able to run them fine